# How to take my widget in QListWidget, using currentItemChanged signal?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I have QListWidget pointer (pListWidget). A have my custom (QCustomItem) widget, inerited from QWidget and containing some data. I adding some widgets into the list:

```
int iMyData = 555;
...
QListWidgetItem *pListWidgetItem = new QListWidgetItem();
QCustomItem *pCustomWidget = new QCustomItem(iMyData);
pListWidget->addItem(pListWidgetItem);
pListWidget->setItemWidget(pListWidgetItem, pCustomWidget);
...
```

This part of code may be in cycle (adding few widgets).

Also I detecting item changing by connection:

```
connect(pListWidget, SIGNAL(currentItemChanged(QListWidgetItem*,QListWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(slotItemChanged(QListWidgetItem*,QListWidgetItem*)) );
```

And slot realization:

```
void QSomeForm::slotItemChanged(QListWidgetItem* pCurrent, QListWidgetItem* pPrevious)
{
  QCustomItem *pCustomWidget = // And this is my question: how to take my custom widget in this block code using pListWidget and pCurrent?

  // Processing pCustomWidget
  int iMyData = pCustomWidget->iMyData(); // In current example I want to see 555 here
}
```

How I can extract my widget from QListWidget ? Thanks! I hope on your help!

Answer (score 0):

Read the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#itemWidget). If you have found `QListWidget::setItemWidget()` you can find:

```
QWidget * QListWidget::itemWidget(QListWidgetItem * item) const
```

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question! Big thanks! It works!!